# Наименьшее натуральное число, сумма делителей которого не меньше миллиона

Tags: python-3.x, теория-чисел, числовые-последовательности

Рассмотрим последовательность: 1, 6, 48, 360, 3120, 27720, ?

Энный элемент этой последовательности равен наименьшему натуральному числу, имеющему эн-значную сумму делителей (включая 1 и само число). Например, сумма делителей числа 360 равна 1170, а у всех чисел, меньших 360, сумма делителей меньше 1000.

Какой член этой последовательности скрывается под знаком вопроса? Иными словами, каково наименьшее натуральное число, сумма делителей которого не меньше миллиона?

Мой швахкод (эвфемизм к слову «авнакод») работает слишком медленно:

```
def sumdiv(n):
    summa=0
    for a in range (1, n+1):
        if n%a==0:
            summa+=a
    return summa 
    
i=1
while sumdiv(i)<1000000:
    i+=1
print(i, sumdiv(i))
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как его ускорить?

Comment: А я вижу, Вы любите задачки из теории чисел. я до третьего курса учился на кафедре теории чисел, поэтому мне они тоже нравятся.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По аналогии с решетом Эратосфена: https://ideone.com/17WrNg

```
n = 1000000
d = [1] * (n+1)
 
for x in range(2, len(d)):
  for y in range(x, len(d), x):
    d[y] += x
 
i = next(i for i,x in enumerate(d) if x >= n)
print(i)
```

```
249480
```

Если верить онлайн-калькулятору (самому было лень писать), то число имеет 160 делителей

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 27, 28, 30, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45, 54, 55, 56, 60, 63, 66, 70, 72, 77, 81, 84, 88, 90, 99,  105,  108,  110,  120,  126,  132,  135,  140,  154,  162,  165,  168,  180,  189,  198,  210,  216,  220,  231,  252,  264,  270,  280,  297,  308,  315,  324,  330,  360,  378,  385,  396,  405,  420,  440,  462,  495,  504,  540,  567,  594,  616,  630,  648,  660,  693,  756,  770,  792,  810,  840,  891,  924,  945,  990, 1080, 1134, 1155, 1188, 1260, 1320, 1386, 1485, 1512, 1540, 1620, 1782, 1848, 1890, 1980, 2079, 2268, 2310, 2376, 2520, 2772, 2835, 2970, 3080, 3240, 3465, 3564, 3780, 3960, 4158, 4455, 4536, 4620, 5544, 5670, 5940, 6237, 6930, 7128, 7560, 8316, 8910, 9240, 10395, 11340, 11880, 12474, 13860, 16632, 17820, 20790, 22680, 24948, 27720, 31185, 35640, 41580, 49896, 62370, 83160,  124740,  249480

А их сумма получается 1045440.

Comment: А вот это крутая идея! Применить аналог решета Эратосфена в этой задаче я не догадался!

Answer (score 3):

Можно запустить тоже самое, что у вас на С++. Вывело ответ(249480) за 2-3 минуты.

```
int64_t sumdiv(int64_t n) {
  int64_t sum = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if(n % i == 0) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int64_t sum = 1;
  int64_t i = 1;
  while(sum < 1000000) {
    i += 1;
    sum = sumdiv(i);
    if(i % 1000 == 0) {
      std::cout << "CURRENT: " << i << " " << sum << std::endl;
   }
  }
  std::cout << "RES: " << sum << " " << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

И более быстрая версия того же самого(от Qwertiy)
(0.9 сек)

```
int64_t sumdiv(int64_t n) {
  int64_t sum = 0, i;
  for(i = 1; i * i < n; ++i) {
    if(n % i == 0) {
      sum += i + n/i;
    }
  }
  return sum + (i*i==n ? i : 0);
}
 
int main()
{
  int64_t sum = 0;
  int64_t i = 1;
  while(sum < 1000000) {
    i += 1;
    sum = sumdiv(i);
  }
  std::cout << "RES: " << sum << " " << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: у Вас функция sumdiv() даёт неверный ответ уже на аргументе=6: якобы sumdiv(6)=9, в то время как на самом деле sumdiv(6)=12. Вы не учитывааете пр суммировании "вторую половинку" делителя в строке sum += i;

Comment: Кажется, правильная реализация функции sumdiv(), умеющей делить только до корня из числа, такая: int64_t sumdiv(int64_t n) {
  int64_t sum = 1 + n;
  int i=2;
  for(i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i) {
    if(n % i == 0) {
      if (i*i==n)
        sum += i;
      else
        sum += i+n/i;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

Comment: Поправил первую реализацию, теперь работает.

Comment: Пока всё еще не совсем правильно, проверьте на числе 6. И гляньте в мою реализацию. Мне кажется, имеет смысл подправить и результат в ответе: 249480

Comment: У меня для первой реализации sumdiv(16) = 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 +2 + 16, т.к. я не был уверен, что имели ввиду. И там ответ соответственно другой(978120 - это уже поправленный).

Comment: По моему, сумма делителей числа - это довольно однозначная штука. Можно проверить две реализации = "медленную и правильную", которая фактически есть в вопросе, и "быструю", сравнивая между собой результаты на каком то заметном диапазоне чисел

Comment: Очень неправильно. Если взять 700000, то всего двух делителей хватит, чтобы получить больше миллиона: 700000 + 350000 = 1050000. У меня получился ответ 249480.

Comment: @Qwertiy Там ответ, на изначальный вопрос чуть ниже 249480

Comment: @S.H., ты вроде пока реализацию не добавил?

Comment: я имел в виду комментарий, где поправил функцию из ответа vlad9i2 - это второй комментарий в этой ветке

Comment: @vlad9i2, ладно, вижу, хотя 2-3 минуты - это доооооооооолго. А первый код что делает? Вот небольшое изменение второго кода и считает за .9 секунды: https://ideone.com/dDmfKW.

Comment: Добавил быструю версию второго кода ещё

Comment: Планировалось, что будет выводиться сумма простых делителей + 1 + n :).  Да ваш код лучше, наверное его в пост вставлю.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте представим себе, что у нас есть разложение числа на его собственные множители (множители, отличные от единицы и от самого числа): `N = m1*m2*m3*...*mk`

Тогда все делители этого числа - это все комбинации множителей.

Соответственно, сумма делителей - это сумма всех уникальных комбинаций из произведений этих множителей.

Этот алгоритм - разложение на множители, а потом их комбинирование - будет быстрее, потому что для каждого N он требудет перебора не более, чем корень из N попыток деления (это самый плохой случай, когда число является квадратом простого числа).

Поэтому, думаю, такой алгоритм будет работать быстрее, чем перебор всех делителей.

Дальнейшее ускорение алогоритма можно получить, если памяти достаточно много, чтобы держать в ней таблицу простых чисел, и проверять делимость не на все делители, а только на простые.

Сейчас я постараюсь написать этот алгоритм на питончике - давно не пользовался им, а иногда он очень выручает.

Comment: А если вообще не использовать разложение?